# How to increase the duration of an animation if several triggers happen before finishing it?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I have a simple color animation:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource xxx}" Text="{Binding DataContext.Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataCell}}}" >
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ValueChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataCell}}}" Value="True">
                     <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" From="{StaticResource NormalForeground}" To="{StaticResource ModifiedForeground}" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                     </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

As you can see it happens when DataContext.ValueChanged is true. This is a boolean value that goes true -> false each time its needed. Normally the animation takes 1 second to execute and what I want is to extend the time if more than one DataContext.ValueChanged happens while the animation is already running.

So if I do:

```
                   DataContext.ValueChanged: start animation for 1 second.
After 0.5 seconds: DataContext.ValueChanged: the animation will last 1.5 second.
After 1.0 seconds: DataContext.ValueChanged: the animation will last 1.5 second more.
```

Essentially each time the value DataContext.ValueChanged goes true a second is added to the ColorAnimation and it must retain the To: color until it has to start the face out.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have in the viewmodel code like this:

```
(...)
if (condition)
{
    this.ValueChanged = true;
    this.ValueChanged = false;
}
(...)
```

*This code gets called each second and the animation duration is set to one second as well* so if condition is meet the expected output is that the TextBox retains the To color until the condition is false and then the fade off to the From color is executed.

Hope now is more clear!

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a project that demonstrates the problem. Execute it and type on the TextBox, if you type faster than one second per key the text should remain red. When you decrease to less that one second per key the animation should be completely executed:

[Project source and binaries](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/451730/AnimationTest.zip)

**EDIT 3:**

Added the source code of the project here:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Background="#444444">
        <TextBox Name="Box" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="White" Background="#444444" >

        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" >
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ValueChanged}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard >
                                        <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" From="White" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CODE:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace AnimationTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _text;
        private bool _valueChanged;

        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
                this.ValueChanged = true;
                this.ValueChanged = false;
            }
        }

        public bool ValueChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return _valueChanged;
            }
            set
            {
                _valueChanged = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("ValueChanged");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you provide a code example that *actually* demonstrates your problem, then you might get more answers.

Comment: @Sheridan: hi, I've added more code to show what I'm doing and what I expect. Thanks!

Comment: Does your code demonstrate your problem? No. If you paste that into a new project, you'll see that.

Comment: @Sheridan: Added a sample project that demonstrates the issue. Thanks.

Comment: My friend, I have no intention on downloading anything, as there could be anything on the end of that link. This website works with question authors asking questions and providing all of the relevant code required to recreate your problem right here. If your project is too big, then [*create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new project and show us that instead. I often find my own bugs while performing this step before asking a question, so it's well worth doing. However, it's up to you.

Comment: @Sherida: I always do the minimal example before posting but I thought that would be more comfortable for you to download the project, that's why I posted the link. Anyway, attached the source code were you can reproduce the problem. The expected result is to maintain the text red while adding text regularly. I understand your point, thanks for your help.

Comment: Didn't I already help you with this problem? For a minute, just forget all this `ValueChanged` business... tell me exactly what you are trying to achieve? What are your requirements, regardless of implementation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56274/discussion-between-somos-and-sheridan).

Comment: I don't have time to chat... just enough to pop back every now and again

Comment: Chat is not a real chat, it's just a way to avoid populating the comments section too much. Anyway here my answer: Hi Sheridan, you already help me with a problem with this feature but a different one. Now I have a From / To so the fade out works correctly. The requirements are: a value can get updated once a second. The first time it gets updated it must animate from normal color to modified color. If several updates arrive continuously the color must remain as modified color. When no more updates arrive the color must animate from modified to normal. Hope this clarify the issue.

Comment: Interesting... and complicated. Perhaps you need two `ColorAnimation`s... one to turn the text red and the other to turn it back to white? You could handle the first one as you are now (without the `RepeatBehavior`) and the other one could be started from the code behind from a `DispatcherTimer.Tick` event handler, which is set to have a one second `Interval` and started in the `Text` setter.